# Creating a rich-text editor interface

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am new to html forms. I am trying to create TextArea that has an HTML interface (rich text editor interface). I do not an have idea on how to begin. I am using PHP and JavaScript on my site.

Can somebody please give me a hint?

Comment: Either way I don't have the answer for you but you should be more specific.  Are you wanting to know how to install a drop in pre made tool for a problem that's already been solved may times over? Or are you wanting a tutorial on how they work under the hood?  Each is valid, it just doesn't seem clear which you want an answer to.

Answer (score 2):

You need javascript to have a rich text area. 
read this link for more details: http://superdit.com/2011/05/21/12-jquery-based-rich-text-editor/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean something like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) it is a JavaScript solution and can be integrated with any server side language.